# How to efficiently merge single tiffs with compression in Azure container app without hitting resource limits?

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, tiff, libtiff

I'm currently working on an .Net 6 Azure container app (2 CPU/4 GB RAM) where I need to merge multiple single tiffs into a multiframe one and apply compression. Initially, I tried using ImageMagick's convert and tiffcp CLI tools for this task. However, as the number of pages reaches 50-100, the container crashes due to exceeding resource limits for RAM/storage and restarts.

I attempted to mitigate this issue by editing ImageMagick's policy.xml to reduce the resource using limits, but this resulted in a "cache exhausted" error.

Are there alternative approaches or optimizations that can be implemented to efficiently merge single tiffs with compression in an Azure container app without encountering resource limitations? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How many images? How large images? How do you merge the images? You will likely need to keep the resulting image in memory. Just make sure to calculate the total size *first*, and then copy each of the source images into the resulting image.